# Isomorphism Between Two Subgroups of $GL_2(\mathbb{F})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Good day! I am struggling with the following question in my group theory class for quite some time and would love to recieve a hint:

> Let $\mathbb{F}$ denote some field and $\mathbb{F^*} = \mathbb{F} \setminus \{0\}$.
> Let us define the following sets:
> \begin{gather*}
>     Q = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix}
>         \alpha & \beta \\
>         0 & 1
>     \end{pmatrix} : \: \alpha \in \mathbb{F^*}, \beta \in \mathbb{F} \right\} \\
>     P = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix}
>         \alpha & \beta \\
>         0 & \alpha^{-1}
>     \end{pmatrix} : \: \alpha \in \mathbb{F^*}, \beta \in \mathbb{F} \right\}
> \end{gather*}
> Show that both $P$ and $Q$ are groups with regard to matrix multiplication and that they are isomorphic.

The first part of the question (showing that these are in facts groups) may be a little bit tricky because of the notation, specifically that $\alpha^{-1}$ denotes the multiplicative inverse as opposed to the additive inverse.
However, once understood, it is quite technical to show both are groups for example by showing these are subgroups of $GL_2(\mathbb{F})$.

Showing that these are isomorphic is the part of the question I had to think about for quite some time without any progress really.
Firstly, I tried to construct a group isomorphism directly (naively), simply by defining:
\begin{gather*}
    \varphi: P \rightarrow Q \\
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \alpha & \beta \\
        0 & \alpha^{-1}
    \end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
        \alpha & \beta \\
        0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{gather*}
Quite expectedly, it doesn't work, as this map is not homomorphic. One can easily verify by taking two generic elements of $P$ (I add the calculation at the end as it's probably not too relevant but maybe it will wake some ideas up).
I tried some other maps that seemed natural, but wasn't able to find an isomorphism.

I thought maybe a better direction would be to use some isomorphism theorem but can't really see how it would be possible to apply one here.
I also tried to find some groups that both $Q$ and $P$ are naturally isomorphic too, but wasn't really able to find one - I think if that was the case I would be able to find a direct isomorphism between them.

Any hints regarding this problem would be extremely appreciated! (costed me some hours of sleep this one :D) Thank you so much and have a lovely day!

A calculation that shows why $\varphi$ is not a homomorphism:

> For some $A = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha_1 & \beta_1 \\ 0 & \alpha_1^{-1} \end{pmatrix}$, $B = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha_2 & \beta_2 \\ 0 & \alpha_2^{-1} \end{pmatrix} \in P$: \begin{gather*} \varphi(AB) = \begin{pmatrix}        \alpha_1 \alpha_2 & \alpha_1 \beta_2 + \beta_1 \alpha_2^{-1} \\     0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \\ \varphi(A)\varphi(B) = \begin{pmatrix}    \alpha_1 \alpha_2 & \alpha_1 \beta_2 + \beta_1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \end{gather*}

Comment: $Q$ is the affine group ${\rm Aff}(F)$, so we know at least that this is a subgroup of $GL_2(F)$. It is isomorphic to $F\rtimes F$. It is not a subgroup of $SL_2(F)$ (but $P$ is).

Comment: That is correct! $Q$ is very naturally isomorphic to $Aff(\mathbb{F})$. I wasn't able to take advantage of this fact. From a geometric standpoint it seems a little weird that these groups are isomorphic, but that doesn't really mean anything. $P \leq SL_2(\mathbb{F})$.

Comment: I have shown that $Q$ is isomorphic to $F \rtimes F^*$... But can't really work out $P$. I shall try again.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Do you mean $F\rtimes F$ or $F\rtimes F^*$? When talking about semidirect products, you should also mention the homomorphism which defines the product.

Comment: The homomorphism used to define the semidirect product is simply: Given $[A]_{ij} \in Q$, $A \rightarrow a_{1,1} \times_F a_{1,2}$

Comment: I see a counting problem here.  Have you tried counting the number of involutions in $Q$ vs $P$?  When $\text{char }\mathbb F \neq 2$ (esp when $\text{char }\mathbb F =0$),  I see 2 involutions in $Q$ and $\gt 2$  in $P$.

Comment: Is this even correct? If $\mathbb{F}$ is the field of $3$ elements, I think $Q \cong S_3$ while $P \cong \mathbb{Z}_6$.

Comment: I am trying to test whether $P$ is cyclic while $Q$ isn't for $F = \mathbb{Z_3}$ as @sTertooy suggested. If it is the case I'll have to ask the professor who came up with this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $\text{char }\mathbb F \neq 2$:

$P$ has exactly 2 involutions:
$ \big\{-I,I\big\}$ because an involution has eigenvalues of $1$ and/or $-1$ but $\alpha=\alpha^{-1}$ so the diagonal is constant.  Now use the fact that an involution must be diagonalizable (in $GL_n(\mathbb F)$) $\implies \beta =0$.

But $Q$ has at least 4 involutions, given by $\left\{ I, \begin{pmatrix}
        -1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
        -1 & 1 \\
        0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
        -1 & -1 \\
        0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}\right\}$

conclude: any homomorphism $\psi: Q\longrightarrow P$ cannot be injective, contradicting the existence of an isormoprhism $\varphi: P\longrightarrow Q$.